# dump file oracle 11 docker

Tags: oracle, impdp

I used docker oracle database [Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g)
I tried to import a file dmp, but i have the bellow error

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  oracle:
    image: jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g
    container_name: oracle11g
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/data:/u01/app/oracle jaspeen/oracle-xe-11g
    ports:
      - "1529:1521"
      - "8081:8080"
      - "2222:22"
```

**command**

```
docker exec -it oracle11g sqlplus
Enter user-name: SYS as SYSDBA
Enter password: oracle

SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE DEV_SPACE DATAFILE 'dev_space.dat' SIZE 500M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M;
SQL> DEFINE NEW_USER = 'scoemploi';
SQL> CREATE USER &NEW_USER. IDENTIFIED BY "1234";
SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE JOB, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ANY CONTEXT TO &NEW_USER;
SQL> ALTER USER &NEW_USER QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
SQL> ALTER USER &NEW_USER DEFAULT TABLESPACE DEV_SPACE;


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY docker_vol AS '/u01/app/oracle';
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY docker_vol TO scoemploi;

sudo docker exec -it oracle11g impdp scoemploi/1234 DUMPFILE=docker_vol:scoemploi2020.DMP FULL=Y


ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "/u01/app/oracle/scoemploi2020.DMP" for read
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have scoemploi2020.DMP inside your docker

docker cp /hostpath/scoemploi2020.DMP demo1:/u01/app/oracle

docker exec -it demo1 chmod +rxw /u01/app/oracle/scoemploi2020.DMP

Comment: the error change to "ORA-39143: dump file "/u01/app/oracle/scoemploi2020.DMP" may be an original export dump file"

Comment: - that is the version of the source database ?

Comment: - are your sure it the a dump generated by datapump , exppd ?  maybe it is a legacy dump ?

Comment: Frankly i don't know :( what can i do?

Comment: what is the result of string scoemploi2020.DMP | head -3

Comment: take a look at: http://www.acehints.com/2013/04/how-to-identify-check-find-out-oracle.html

Comment: EXPORT:V10.02.01
DSCOEMPLOI2
RUSERS

Comment: it is a legacy export file, you need to use imp command to import it.  https://www.oracle-dba-online.com/how-to-use-import-tool.htm